# Angular create searchbar for Firestore

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

i try to create a searchbar to query data from Firestore and show the results in a list. To do so i created the following:

```
export class SearchComponentComponent implements OnInit  {


ngOnInit(): void {

}
searchValue: string = "";
results: any;

 constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore) {
 }

 search() {
  let self = this;
   self.results = self.afs.collection(`Blogs`, ref => ref
  .orderBy("title")
  .startAt(self.searchValue.toLowerCase())
  .endAt(self.searchValue.toLowerCase()+"\uf8ff")
  .limit(10))
  .valueChanges();
 }

 }
```

and my HTML:

```
<div>
 <input type="text" (keyup)="search()" [(ngModel)]="searchValue"  
placeholder="search 
 movies..." >
<div class="search-results">
 <div class="search-result" *ngFor="let result of results | async">
  {{ result.title }}
</div>
```

The problem now is that i dont get any data.
One Blog child contains the following data:

> Title, Body, Image

I want to show the title in my results list

Comment: the three items are with small letters at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';

@Component({
selector: 'app-search-component',
templateUrl: './search-component.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./search-component.component.css']
})
export class SearchComponentComponent implements OnInit  {

 displayedColumns = ['ImageUrl'];

 ngOnInit(): void {
}
 searchValue: string = "";
 dataSource: any;

 constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore) {
 }





 getStudents() {
this.dataSource = this.afs.collection('Blogs', ref => ref.where('title', '==', this.searchValue)).valueChanges();
}
```

}